# Using different appendix heading style than chapter heading

Tags: fancyhdr

I would like to change the heading style for the appendices included in my document whilst maintaining the style for all previous chapters.

Currently I have this in my .tex file:

```
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\include{C0/Declarations}
\include{C0/Abstract}
\include{C0/Acknowledgements}
\include{C0/Dedication}
\include{C0/Quote}
\include{C0/Nomenclature}
\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\printnomenclature

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\doublespacing
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\include{C1/chapter1}
\include{C2/chapter2}
\include{C3/chapter3}
\include{C4/chapter4}
\include{C5/chapter5}
\include{C6/chapter6}
\appendix
\include{CA1/chapterA1}
\include{CA2/chapterA2}
\end{document}
```

How can I change this so that for the appendices I have a heading without the white space above and have the header with text on all appendix pages (Currently the header does not appear on the first page of each appendix).

Thanks,

Jaspreet.

Answer (score 0):

Fancyhdr allows you to change settings within a document. Just put a new definition block after your `\appendix`, before `\include{CA1/chapterA1}`. The new command will override the last one.

For what it's worth, this is already happening in your main definition block:

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
```

Where the last `\fancyfoot` overrides the first one. You might want to delete one or the other.

Cheers

Comment: Hi Richard. Sorry, I should have been clearer in the question. I want to change the formatting of the chapter title i.e. "Appendix A", "Appendix B" etc. Right now they are formatted so they appear a third down from the top of the page which doesn't leave enough room to insert an image into the same page. Is there a way to change the formatting of these chapter headings to something similar to a section heading where the title appears right at the top of the page? Thanks.